# Set current directory when running a Python project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python project which I want to run, let's say the folder is called `foo`. The folder contains an `__init__.py`. If I run it like this:

```
~ $ ls foo/
__init__.py
img.png
# etc...

~ $ python -m foo
# Traceback, img.png not found
```

How can I access `img.png` from the project without modifying it? I have tried `python -m .` in `foo/` (error: `Relative module names not supported`) and `python __init__.py` in `foo/` (error: `No module named 'foo'` because the `__init__.py` requires files in the project).

What should I do? The author uses an IDE to run it.

Edit: I do not want to modify the source-code, I want to know how I can run it without any modification. The author can do it, I suppose I can too.